# Sequelize, Raw Query by daterange

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I use "sequelize": "^2.0.0-rc3" with pg (postgresql), in this moment i am trying to do a **raw query** with date range but sequelize don't return data.

When I run the same query in postgresql db get correct results. Please Help Me.

In sequilize:

```
  // Init main query
  var query = "SELECT * FROM" + '"Calls"' +
              " WHERE "  + '"EquipmentId"' + " = 1" +
              " AND " + '"initDate"' + " >= " + "'2015-02-05 14:40' " +
              " AND " + '"endDate"' + " <= " + " '2015-02-05 15:00' ";

  global.db.sequelize.query(query)
  .then(function(calls) {
    console.log(calls);
  })
  .error(function (err) {
    console.log(err);
  });
```

In console of node server I get.

```
Executing (default): SELECT * FROM "Calls" WHERE "EquipmentId" = 1 AND "initDate" >= '2015-02-05 14:40'  AND "endDate" <=  '2015-02-05 15:00'
```

But empty array calls...

Comment: What happens if you use `psql` to run that exact query?

Comment: The problem is that sequelize doesn't have the time part. How to add time part to sequelize.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
var query = ' \
  SELECT * FROM "Calls" \
  WHERE "EquipmentId" = :EquipmentId \
  AND "initDate" >= :initDate \
  AND "endDate" <= :endDate; \
';

global.db.sequelize.query(query, null, {raw: true}, { 
  EquipmentId: 1, 
  initDate: new Date('2015-02-05 14:40'), 
  endDate: new Date('2015-02-05 15:00')
})
.then(function(calls) {
  console.log(calls);
})
.error(function (err) {
  console.log(err);
});
```

Comment: ```bash
Executing (default): SELECT * FROM "Calls"   WHERE "EquipmentId" = :EquipmentId   AND "initDate" >= :initDate   AND "endDate" <= :endDate;
Possibly unhandled TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of null
```

Comment: I've updated my answer, try adding null as the second parameter, eg. db.sequelize.query(query, null, {raw: true},

Comment: It is so perfect, I get the calls yeah, mmm in ```bash
console.log(calls)
```

Comment: Only one more question, Why? Now I get **node console** 
```bash
Executing (default): SELECT * FROM "Calls"   WHERE "EquipmentId" = 1   AND "initDate" >= '2015-02-05 19:40:00.000 +00:00'   AND "endDate" <= '2015-02-05 20:00:00.000 +00:00';
```
And this is perfect...

Comment: Yeah it is perfect, but i want to understand really well.

Comment: If it works, then please mark my answer is correct. Instead of doing string concatenation, I used a parameterized query, and let Sequelize convert the JavaScript Date object to proper PostgresSQL format.

Comment: say... Votes up requires 15 reputation

Answer (score 1):

You can also use sequelize function like [`findAll`](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/class/lib/model.js~Model.html#static-method-findAll)

```
Model.findAll(
  where : {    
     gte:sequelize.fn('date_format', initDate, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%i:%s'),
     lte:sequelize.fn('date_format', endDate, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%i:%s')
  }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

To get a result between two date ranges you just need to do this.

```
let whereClause = { 
  where: {  $and: [  
           { time: { [ Op.gte ]: req.query.start_time } },
           { time: { [ Op.lte ]: req.query.end_time } } 
           ] 
       }
 };

 await model_name.findAll(whereClause);
```